# How to sort folder names with natsort in Python that I got with os.walk?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, os.walk, natsort

I am new to Python.
I have to crawl trough many folders and check for a specific file. If this file is in this folder the name of the folder will be appended at the end of a list. After that I want the names of the folder to be sorted naturally. 
I tried `natsorted(filename)`, of the natsort package but somehow it didn't sort the list.

My code:

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(folder):
if mat_file in fileList:
    input_path = dirName + r"\file.txt"
    if os.path.isfile(input_path):
        filename.append(str(dirName.strip(folder)))

natsorted(filename)
print filename
```

`folder` is the path to the folders

I got:

```
['1.1', '1.10', '1.2', '1.4', '1.6', '2.1', '2.10', '2.11', '2.12', '2.6']
```

I want:

`['1.1', '1.2', '1.4', '1.6', '1.10', '2.1', '2.6', '2.10', '2.11', '2.12']`

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `natsorted` like `sorted` doesn't mutate the list like `.sort()` would, you need to assign the return value of `natsorted(filename)` back to the `filename` variable like:

```
filename = natsorted(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split each version string to compare it as a list of integers:

filename.sort(key=lambda s: map(int, s.split('.')))

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_key(x):
    a, b = x.split('.')
    return int(a), int(b)

sorted(filename, key=sort_key)
```